# Add value to first index of value 0 in Java array

Tags: java

If I have an array of zeros [0,0,0] how do I insert a given value to the first index that is valued 0.

So first off the value 3 will go into index 0 giving me [3,0,0]

Then the second value 8 will go into index 1 giving me [3,8,0].

How do I go about this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the values in an array like this

```
int[] values = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
values[0] = 3;
values[1] = 8;
```

or if you really want to target the first index that is 0

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++) {
    if(values[i]==0){ // do stuff; break; }
}
```

Comment: The second option is something like what I have but say I pass in 3, the array gets filled with 3's eg, [3,3,3]. How do I break?

Comment: Never mind. I see it now in @daniel's answer. Thank you.

Comment: Had it in mine aswell in the comment

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] values = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
replaceFirstZeroValue( 3, values);
replaceFirstZeroValue( 8, values);

public void replaceFirstZeroValue(int value, int[] array){
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] == 0){
   array[i] = value;
   break;
  }
 }
}
```